# How to translate statement into First Order Logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics

|S∆T| = 1 into first-order logic.
I was given x ∈ y and x ∈ y,but I'm not sure how to begin the problem. I wrote out something to represent s∆T, but I'm not sure how to write the cardinality in first order logic. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If a set is a singleton, then any two members must be the same.

Comment: What has x and y to do with S and T?

Comment: x is an element of S, and T.

Comment: What about  y? ?

Answer (score 0):

The statement does not translate into FOL.
It translates into a FOL with $\in$ as a binary propositional constant added along with a set of axioms for some choice of set theory.  Whereupon definitions for cardinality and $\Delta$ ensue.
After all of that ado, your statement, as is, is stated in a FOL.

The given x,y are so vague, they become useless.
You have not given sufficient context for the problem to be answered.
There are different ways of defining cardinality, depending upon which set theory is used.  One can however short cut all of this by revising the problem to stating there is exactly one element in S$\Delta$T, into a FOL formula.

To say there is exactly one x such that P(x) in a FOL with equality one uses,
exists x with P(x) and for all x,y. (P(x) and P(y) implies x = y).